# Sum of a random number of random variables and its distribution

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

Let ${(X_i)}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables on the probability space $( \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P )$ and let $N : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$ be an integer-valued random variable independent from ${(X_i)}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$.

I am in interested in showing the following:

1. $S := X_1 + \ldots + X_{N}$ is a random variable, i.e., $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.
2. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$P(S \leq x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P( N = k) P(X_1+\ldots+X_k \leq x).$$

---

An attempt at the second part:

\begin{align}
P(S \leq x) = P \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{ N } X_i \leq x \right)= E \left( 1_{ \left\{ \sum_{i = 1}^{ N } X_i \leq x \right\} } \right) \overset{\text{Tower property}}{=} E \left( E \left( 1_{ \left\{ \sum_{i = 1}^{ N } X_i \leq x \right\} } \mid \sigma(N)\right) \right)=...
\end{align}

---

How can one use the independence property to continue the chain of arguments? Is there maybe a better way to approach this? And, of course, how can one show that $S$ is itself a random variable in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part observe that for every $x\in\mathbb R$ we have:$$\left\{ S\leq x\right\} =\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\left\{ N=k\right\} \cap\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}\leq x\right\} \right)$$ showing that $\{S\leq x\}$ is a measurable set.

This is enough to conclude that $S$ is a random variable.

Second part can be solved by:$$P\left(S\leq x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P\left(N=k\right)P\left(S\leq x\mid N=k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P\left(N=k\right)P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}\leq x\mid N=k\right)=$$$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P\left(N=k\right)P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}\leq x\right)$$
where the last equality is based on independence.

Comment: Thanks! What I noticed is that we could alternatively apply $P$ directly to the union of the disjoint sets above, i.e. consider $P \left( \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\left\{ N=k\right\} \cap\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}\leq x\right\} \right) \right)$ which yields the result. It may also be worthwhile to mention that when conditioning upon the values of $N$, we implicitly exclude the terms with $P( N = k ) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, if we practicize well known definition $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ then using conditional approach we come indeed in trouble if $P(N=k)=0$ is possible. Personally I avoid this definition with fractions and choose instead for the (somehow defining) equality $P(B)P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)$ that also works if $P(B)=0$ and we just "choose" for an "appropriate value" of $P(A\mid B)$. Which value we choose then is not relevant for the solution.